# Mysql service refuses to start - /sys/devices/system/cpu/ read fail

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, services

mysqld service refuses to start.

```
sudo service mysql start
```

See listing below.
Running `mysql_upgrade` did not help.

I found some forum posts that it happens after Ubuntu upgrade, but found no solution.

Anyone knows how to fix? Thanks.

Update: Tried 
`sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`
and add `/sys/devices/system/cpu/`. Didn't help.

Update 2:

Moved on using:

```
$ cat /var/log/daemon.log

Jul 27 11:40:06 ondra-redhat /etc/init.d/mysql[1497]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Jul 27 11:40:06 ondra-redhat /etc/init.d/mysql[1497]: /etc/init.d/mysql: line 75: /usr/bin/mysqladmin: File doesn't exist.

$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.1
...
```

Now it is:

```
Jul 27 12:04:50 ondra-redhat /etc/init.d/mysql[5913]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Jul 27 12:04:50 ondra-redhat /etc/init.d/mysql[5913]: #007/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
Jul 27 12:04:50 ondra-redhat /etc/init.d/mysql[5913]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Jul 27 12:04:50 ondra-redhat /etc/init.d/mysql[5913]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!


    [8589966.601336] type=1400 audit(1343380526.258:9082): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=308 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=309 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589966.708033] type=1400 audit(1343380526.362:9083): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=327 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=328 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589967.768430] type=1400 audit(1343380527.426:9084): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=340 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=341 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589968.776121] type=1400 audit(1343380528.430:9085): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=350 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=351 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589969.784022] type=1400 audit(1343380529.438:9086): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=362 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=363 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589970.791553] type=1400 audit(1343380530.446:9087): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=372 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=373 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589971.799176] type=1400 audit(1343380531.454:9088): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=384 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=385 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589972.807000] type=1400 audit(1343380532.462:9089): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=394 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=395 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589973.814536] type=1400 audit(1343380533.470:9090): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=405 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=406 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589974.822025] type=1400 audit(1343380534.482:9091): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=416 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=417 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589975.829509] type=1400 audit(1343380535.486:9092): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=426 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=427 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589976.837076] type=1400 audit(1343380536.494:9093): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=436 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=437 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589977.844707] type=1400 audit(1343380537.502:9094): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=446 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=447 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589978.852981] type=1400 audit(1343380538.510:9095): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=456 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=457 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589979.860772] type=1400 audit(1343380539.518:9096): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=466 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=467 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589980.868339] type=1400 audit(1343380540.522:9097): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=476 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=477 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [8589980.875425] type=1400 audit(1343380540.530:9098): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=485 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/cpu/" pid=486 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0



$ sudo mysql_upgrade -p --force
Enter password: 
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log
Error    : You can't use locks with log tables.
status   : OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.slow_log
Error    : You can't use locks with log tables.
status   : OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK
mysql.user_info                                    OK
test.payments                                      OK
test.users                                         OK
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
OK
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I had mysql-server-core-5.1 installed, but the apparmor configuration was in mysql-server metapackage. `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` updated `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and it started working.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the answer when you found it :)